# How to reset MongoDB's collection statistics?

Tags: mongodb

Today I've been working on a performance test with **MongoDB**. Once I managed to use all the left space of my hard disk so the test was halted at the middle. So I removed some of the files and restarted the test after a `db.dropDatabase();`. But I noticed that the results of `db.collection.stats();` seems to be wrong now.

My question is, how can I make MongoDB reset / recalculate statistics of a collection?

Comment: Do you mean `db.collection.stats()`?  In what way are the statistics wrong?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure if it's wrong, but my test database with 100M documents (each with two fields, of an `int` and a `date` type) is as big as `"storageSize" : 8683839472` while its index is `"totalIndexSize" : 5769288112`. It would be nice if I could make sure of the statistics by resetting them.

Comment: There's nothing in the docs that imply it's not always up to date so those values are correct.

Comment: stats shows what is true "now" - I would trust them unless you have some evidence of data corruption.  Maybe you can include the stats you think are "wrong" and what you think the right numbers would be?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mongodb is keeping space for the data and indexes it "knows" you will need when you run the test again, even though there is no data there at the moment.

What files did you delete?  If you really don't need the data, you could stop mongod, and delete the other files corresponding to the database - but this is only safe if you are running in a test environment, and not sharing your database.

Comment: The files I deleted were not a part of mongo. The only space I freed from mongo I did using `dropDatabase`.

Comment: Good - deleting database files is risky unless you know you are on a test system and can afford to lose data.  If that's the case, you can delete mongodb's data files (stored in /data in the install I have) - don't delete the mongo install though unless you enjoy reinstalling software.  If you're testing, it is useful to use a VM so you can start from a clean state each time; if mongo is saving space for the next run, it will skew your results.

Comment: please don't give advice to people to delete files unless it's to delete the entire /data/db directory.  db.dropDatabase() is a perfectly adequate way to get rid of a database without risking breaking anything.

Comment: Agreed that deleting database files is not right in most cases. Mehran is running a performance test.  If the test is to see what happens with an empty database, it makes sense to delete the whole of /data/db, or better still, run the test in a clean virtual machine so it starts from a known state.  If the test is meant to be on a live system, drop the database from mongo and then run the test again - don't worry about the stats.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `db.collectionName.drop()` function, then to reimport your collection using `mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName` to view whether or not those values are correct, quick guess though is that they are correct.

Comment: db.dropDatabase() drops all the collections in the current database, see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/#db.dropDatabase

Comment: At first I did try `db.collectionName.drop()` but it failed with an error saying something about `can not have write lock when storage is full` or something like that. And I kept getting this error even after I freed 10% of my storage. So I decided to use `db.dropDatabase()`.